# Problem with MySQL @Id not defined at random

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a weird problem, that occurs at random.

This is how MySQL database handler for execution looks like:

```
public class DBContext
{
    List<MySqlParameter> _param = new List<MySqlParameter>();
    string _connectionString = Startup._Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

    
    private void Execute(string strSQL, List<MySqlParameter> parameters)
    {

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(strSQL, connection))
            {
                foreach (MySqlParameter param in parameters)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.ParameterName, param.Value);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }}
```

This is my GetMyActiveRentals (here is where exceptions is thrown randomly). Sometime I notice it when I run the method 4-5 times fast after eachother.

```
public Void GetMyActiveRentals(int rentalId)
    {
        var sql = $"SELECT r.*, b.boxNo, b.categoryId, c.name, c.brand FROM Rentals r " +
            $"INNER JOIN Box b LEFT JOIN Category c ON c.id=b.categoryId ON r.boxId=b.id " +
            $"WHERE r.id = @id";

        _param.Clear();
        _param.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", rentalId));

        Execute(sql, _param);
    }
```

Exception thorwn:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution.
Parameter '@id' must be defined.
```

Comment: what is GetData?

Comment: This doesn't look like Java at all. Perhaps it's C#?

Comment: it seems you are writing hql query.am i right? if it is ypu should use : instead of @ but as  chrylis said its not like java code

Comment: Sorry, I tagged "Java" by misstake, its C# .NET.

Comment: @nbk, sorry, I pasted in wrong method... calling method should be "Execute()". I have now update the code.

Comment: Look like nothing wrong in your code, so you should use try catch to know when it happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is basically sound.

Your problem is _param, which could be cleared while executing another query.

`_param` in `GetMyActiveRentals` and other functions should be a **local** variable, which get destroyed after the functions is finished